# Integral of a gradient over a closed loop

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis

I'm working on a physics problem about superconductors and during that this specific closed loop integral came up

$$\oint \boldsymbol{\nabla}\varphi(\boldsymbol{r})\cdot d\boldsymbol{\ell}$$

Function $\varphi(\boldsymbol{r})$ wasn't specified. Is there a way to solve this in general? Or is there an identity that could help me with this? Something like Gauss or Stokes theorem?

Comment: Yes "something like". Namely, [Stokes' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes%27_theorem). What is the rotation of a gradient?

Comment: Oh right, it's 0. That's weird, that doesn't really make sense regarding the physics problem. This integral should lead to quantization of magnetic flux.

Comment: Does the gradient have a singularity in the region enclosed by the loop?

Comment: Yes, that might be the case.